# My T-SQL query to send a JSON blob to an API is not doing anything, and I cannot figure out why

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I'm hoping you're able to assist... I have a query (below) that I am using on SQL Server to send a JSON blob to a Slack incoming webhook to post in a channel. When I run the query, the value `@response` is null, and there is no other activity (nothing on Slack, and no error messages). Can someone please help me find out where I am going wrong?

I know that the webhook URI is fine, because I am able to perform the same action using Powershell. But in this instance I need to use SQL server.

```
DECLARE @object     INT,
        @uri        VARCHAR(200) =  'https://hooks.slack.com/services/[redacted]',
        @response   VARCHAR(MAX),
        @body       VARCHAR(MAX) =  '{
                                        "text":"Hello!",
                                        "username":"My_Bot"
                                    }'

EXEC    sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @object OUT
EXEC    sp_OAMethod @object, 'open', NULL, 'post', @uri, 'false'

EXEC    sp_OAMethod @object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
EXEC    sp_OAMethod @object, 'send', NULL, @body

EXEC    sp_OAMethod @object, 'responseText', @response OUTPUT
SELECT  @response

EXEC    sp_OADestroy @object
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @object` after each call of `sp_OA` methods? Remove `, @response OUTPUT`?

Comment: Thanks @gofr1, got an unresolved server error when I tried to send the payload. Looks like the server is blocking connections.